# Javascript Concate int to html id NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, foreach, concatenation

I am trying to concate an int to my id in my javascript function but somehow id does not work, I get a NaN.

Code:

```
observeBox: function() {
    $('#selection').on('click', function() {
        $selection = $(this).val();
        $selection.forEach(function(currentValue,index,array){
            console.log(index);
            $('#sliderAppend').append(
            +'<div id=\"showInput'+index+'_'+$selection[index]+'\">'
                +'<span class=\"btn btn-primary btn-file\">'
                    +'<span class=\"fileupload-new\">'+$selection[index]+'</span>'
                    +'<input id=\"subtitles_file\" name=\"subtitles_file\" type=\"file\" class="\ImageInput upload\" value=\"\">'
                +'</span>'
                +'<span class=\"fileupload-preview\"></span>'
            +'</div>');
        });
        console.log($selection);
    });
},
```

Basically I get the error in this line:

```
            +'<div id=\"showInput'+index+'_'+$selection[index]+'\">'
```

somehow it cannot concate the index properly.

if I

```
console.log(index);
```

I get correct values.

```
$selection[index]
```

returns me the correct values aswell.

Comment: what is value of `$selection[index]`? it it giving you proper value? check that

Comment: @JayeshChitroda $selection[index] are values like en, ab, as, .... These are printed correctly

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first `+` character from  `+'<div id=\"showInput'+index+'_'+$selection[index]+'\">'`

It should be:

```
'<div id=\"showInput'+index+'_'+$selection[index]+'\">'
```

Having the leading `+` there tries to convert the string that follows it into a number, which fails and gives you `NaN`.

Comment: whops wow this is really the solution, ill accept in a few minutes

Comment: Nice catch, Haresh!

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder